# Best way to store unit information in numpy structured array?

Tags: python, numpy

What is the best way to store the unit information of a column in a numpy structured array?

I tried this here, according to http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

> The field name may also be a 2-tuple of strings where the first string is either a  “title” (which may be any string or unicode string) or meta-data for the field which can be any object, and the second string is the “name” which must be a valid Python identifier.

But how can I access/read this metadata?

```
import numpy as np

dtype = np.dtype([
    ('name', 'S64'),
    (('s', 'read_time'), 'uint16'),
    (('us', 'read_latency'), 'float'),
    (('B', 'read_data'), 'uint64'),
])
my_data = np.zeros(10, dtype=dtype)
```

Comment: This example is a bit oriented since you seem to store units that are always different. If you try for example to use seconds instead of microseconds for the read_latency, your example doesn't work... So the initial question is very good, but the example doesn't point it out enough

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're looking for, you want the "descr" attribute of the dtype:

```
In [12]: my_data.dtype.descr
Out[12]: 
[('name', '|S64'),
 (('s', 'read_time'), '<u2'),
 (('us', 'read_latency'), '<f8'),
 (('B', 'read_data'), '<u8')]

In [13]: my_data.dtype.descr[1]
Out[13]: (('s', 'read_time'), '<u2')

In [14]: my_data.dtype.descr[1][0][0]
Out[14]: 's'
```

Your approach of using this for unit metadata makes sense to me.  Note that dtype also has a "names" tuple with just the field names (without the units).

Comment: thx, I think I prefer the fields attribute, because I can use the name of the column:
    my_data.dtype.fields['read_latency'][-1]
    >>> 'us'

Comment: there is one problem with that solution: e.g. if you add another dtype with
`(('s', 'write_time'), 'uint16'),`

I get an `ValueError: two fields with the same name`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Pint](https://pint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

In the docs it states as one of the features:

> NumPy integration: When you choose to use a NumPy ndarray, its methods
>   and ufuncs are supported including automatic conversion of units. For
>   example numpy.arccos(q) will require a dimensionless q and the units
>   of the output quantity will be radian.

Comment: That doesn't work for structured arrays.  Pint quantity supports only a single unit per ndarray, whereas in a structured array, you'd like to have a unit for each field.

Comment: It also doesn't work for array operations like `np.dot`. I have tried to follow up on https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/issues/470 but got no response. Is this a dead package?

Comment: This looks like what astropy.units uses: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/units/#module-astropy.units